# How to turn off initialization for user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to prevent User Control from being initialized? I want to initialize it by myself, not in the constructor in InitializeComponent(); ?

Comment: Thanks for replies, but the problem is a little bit different. This control isn't mine (it is windows live control). I want all other controls in the page to be properly initialized, and this one should be loaded later, on user demand (it connects to the internet, it is wp7 application). How to achieve this?

Comment: I edited my response.  You should always describe the real problem at hand, not just your proposed solution.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567147/how-do-i-declare-a-c-sharp-web-user-control-but-stop-it-from-initializing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that seems silly, but you have already answered your question; remove the call to `InitializeComponent()`.  Have fun recreating the auto-generated designer code!

EDIT:

Ok, so per your edit we know what the *actual* problem you are trying to solve is:

> Thanks for replies, but the problem is a little bit different. This control isn't mine (it is windows live control). I want all other controls in the page to be properly initialized, and this one should be loaded later, on user demand (it connects to the internet, it is wp7 application). How to achieve this?

Thus, you need to add the control at runtime instead of at design time.  This is easy to do.

```
var ctrl = new SomeControl();
// initialize control properties...

// this is your user control, a control within 
// the user control, whatever the parent should be.
parentControl.Children.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: Thanks, a time ago I posted _actual_ problem and there wasn't any answer :) this is working

Answer (score 3):

Are am not sure why you're doing it. Lazy initialization so not to take time at the construction?

Anyway, create a public method and move InitializeComponent there, also don't forget to create a private field to make sure you don't initialize twice.

```
private bool _isInitialized;

public void InititializeControl()
{
    if(_isInitialized) return;

    _isInitialized = true;
    InitializeComponent();

}
```

then call it at the necessary moment..

Comment: I wouldn't call it "lazy" because anyway it will run on the UI thread, so it won't be done in background

Comment: @EvAlex, you're right, especially with the fact that all XAML has to get initialized on the "only" UI thread no matter what. I guess I should have called it delayed.